# Import class from module to mocha test in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I have a file src/core/version.ts

```
module MyModule.Core {
  /** Version information. */
  export class Version {
    /** The informal version. */
    public static getInformalVersion(): string {
      return "1.0 Beta 1";
    }    
  }
}
export default MyModule.Core.Version;
```

and test test/core/version.test.ts

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import Version from "../../src/core/version";

describe('Version',()=>{
    it('getInformalVersionTest',()=> {
        let number =Version.getInformalVersion();
    assert.isNotNull(number);
    });
});
```

if I run `mocha test --recursive`

all successed but grunt fail

```
error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
```

error in this string

```
 export default MyModule.Core.Version;
```

if I clear it grunt compile project but mocha test fail

```
TS23006 File './src/core/version.ts' is not a module
```

Tell me pleace how to make the import of the class Version into the test version.test.ts

Comment: Compile the TS files with `commonjs` module system

Comment: Do I understand correctly, i correct gruntfile.js `configuration.typescript = {        options: {
            module:"commonjs"
        }
    };` and what after?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import * as fs from "fs";

var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./src/core/version.js", "utf8");
if( fileContent.indexOf("exports.MyModule = MyModule;") === -1 )
    fs.appendFileSync('./src/core/version.js', "\n exports.MyModule = MyModule;");

import * as MyModule from "../../src/core/version.js";
import Version = MyModule.MyModule.Core.Version;
describe('Version',()=>{
    it('getInformalVersionTest',()=> {
        let number =Version.getInformalVersion();
    assert.isNotNull(number);
    });
});
```